# Other expressions for "technology evolution"

Tags: expression-choice

In the last few decades technology has changed many of our daily habits. Making  phone calls, keeping social contacts, booking a hotel or a flight, reading  digital maps, online newspapers, books and dictionaries, just to name a few things that not so many years ago required more time and often  the help of other professional figures. Bad or good this trend, often called technology evolution, is probably going to accelerate in the foreseeable future. What other expressions can you suggest to describe this unavoidable trend.

Comment: I love how each generation has to feel special, as if they were the only ones to know radical change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mankind in a Transition**

is an interesting expression used by Radovan  Richta, the philosopher who coined the expression "[Technology evolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technological_evolution)" that is the name of an innovation & technology related theory describing technology development.

> Technology (which Richta defines as "a material entity created by the application of mental and physical effort to nature in order to achieve some value") **evolves in three stages: tools, machine, automation. This evolution, he says, follows two trends: the replacement of physical labour with more efficient mental labour, and the resulting greater degree of control over one's natural environment, including an ability to transform raw materials into ever more complex and pliable products.**

Answer (score 2):

Many people would regard *onslaught of new technology* and *overwhelming tsunami of tech* as accurate reflections of how they feel about the phenomenon you describe.

Answer (score 1):

The simple word *[progress](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/progress#Noun)* sometimes is used (eg, in phrases like “[That's progress for you](https://www.google.com/#q=that%27s+progress+for+you)” or “[the high price of progress](https://www.google.com/#q=the+high+price+of+progress)”) to encompass the idea that change is rapid, and while perhaps evolutionary, often disconcerting.  *Progress* also is part of the term *[progress trap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progress_trap)*, which refers to

> the condition human societies experience when, in pursuing progress through human ingenuity, they inadvertently introduce problems they do not have the resources or political will to solve, for fear of short-term losses in status, stability or quality of life.

The *progress trap* term suggests that some avenues of evolutionary progress are dead ends.

Answer (score 0):

"The Law of Accelerating Returns" was used by Ray Kurzweil to refer to the phenomenon you described.

http://www.kurzweilai.net/the-law-of-accelerating-returns

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider the terms **exponential**, **accelerating** or **increasing**, with respect to the **pace, progress, advancement** or similar of technology.

For example:

> We live in a time where advances in technology occur *exponentially*. Today's cutting edge tech, maybe obsolete tomorrow.

or

> The *accelerating pace* of technological progression means that new technology is quickly antiquated and needs replacement.

or

> Breakthroughs in technology are occurring with *increasingly shorter* intervals. Where a new model of phone might have taken two years to come to the market, it now takes six months.

You might also consider for an explanation as why technology is progressing at an increasing rate with **feedback effect** or **feedback loop**.

> The *feedback loop* of technological discovery means that technological breakthroughs occur at increasingly shorter intervals. The breakthrough of one technology allows discovery of other technologies, and so the rate of progress is quickened.